# Android In-App Update Feature implementation

Tags: java, android, updates, in-app

I am implementing In-App Update feature in my android application, i am unaware about this concept. Can anyone provide me with example. My Requirement is whenever user clicks a button for update app after login it must show a pop up that update is available or not. If available then proceed for Update. TIA

Answer (score 2):

Google Provides an official solution for this now

Use `AppUpdateManager`

from the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates#java)

> **Check for update availability**
>
> Before requesting an update, you need to first check if one is
>   available for your app. To check for an update, use AppUpdateManager,
>   as shown below:
>
> ```
> // Creates instance of the manager.
> AppUpdateManager appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(context);
>
> // Returns an intent object that you use to check for an update.
> Task<AppUpdateInfo> appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo();
>
> // Checks that the platform will allow the specified type of update.
> appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener(appUpdateInfo -> {
>     if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE
>           // For a flexible update, use AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE
>           && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)) {
>               // Request the update.
>     }
> });
> ```
>
> The result contains the update availability status. If an update is
>   available and the update is allowed, the returned AppUpdateInfo also
>   contains an intent to start the update. See the next section for how
>   to start the update.
>
> If an in-app update is already in progress, the result will also
>   report the status of the in-progress update.

For the complete procedure read [in-app-updates](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates)

Comment: but when i implement this logic by degrading my app version name and code lesser than play store version name and version code, it was not showing any in play store simply showing open and uninstall options in play store.

Answer (score 2):

best way for handle pop up dialogue for update app that you should us remote confige section in fire base . first add firebase requirement to your app then add remote config library to dependency . you can defind key and value in firebase console and fetch it in your splash activity or something like this . check version name application with this value that fetch from remote config and compare two version . if two string is not equal , you should show dialogue for update app.

Answer (score 2):

recently i was implemented the google latest In App Update FLEXIBLE type, its very pretty cool. here i added the button onClickListener, it tells the whether update is available are not and must be api version 21 and above otherwise it won't work.

```
private AppUpdateManager appUpdateManager;
private static final int MY_REQUEST_CODE = 17326;
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                checkUpdate();
            }
        });
    }


    private void checkUpdate(){
        appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this);
        appUpdateManager.registerListener(listener);

        Task<AppUpdateInfo> appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo();
        appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AppUpdateInfo>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(AppUpdateInfo appUpdateInfo) {
                Log.d("appUpdateInfo :", "packageName :"+appUpdateInfo.packageName()+ ", "+ "availableVersionCode :"+ appUpdateInfo.availableVersionCode() +", "+"updateAvailability :"+ appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() +", "+ "installStatus :" + appUpdateInfo.installStatus() );

                if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE
                        && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(FLEXIBLE)){
                    requestUpdate(appUpdateInfo);
                    Log.d("UpdateAvailable","update is there ");
                    }
                else if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == 3){
                          Log.d("Update","3");
                        notifyUser();
                }
                else
                    {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Update Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("NoUpdateAvailable","update is not there ");
                }
            }
        });
    }
    private void requestUpdate(AppUpdateInfo appUpdateInfo){
        try {
            appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(appUpdateInfo,AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE,MainActivity.this,MY_REQUEST_CODE);
            resume();
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == MY_REQUEST_CODE){
            switch (resultCode){
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    if(resultCode != RESULT_OK){
                        Toast.makeText(this,"RESULT_OK" +resultCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d("RESULT_OK  :",""+resultCode);
                    }
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:

                    if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED){
                        Toast.makeText(this,"RESULT_CANCELED" +resultCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d("RESULT_CANCELED  :",""+resultCode);
                    }
                    break;
                case ActivityResult.RESULT_IN_APP_UPDATE_FAILED:

                    if (resultCode != RESULT_IN_APP_UPDATE_FAILED){

                        Toast.makeText(this,"RESULT_IN_APP_UPDATE_FAILED" +resultCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d("RESULT_IN_APP_FAILED:",""+resultCode);
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    InstallStateUpdatedListener listener = new InstallStateUpdatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStateUpdate(InstallState installState) {
            if (installState.installStatus() == InstallStatus.DOWNLOADED){
                Log.d("InstallDownloded","InstallStatus sucsses");
                notifyUser();
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        appUpdateManager.unregisterListener((InstallStateUpdatedListener) this);
    }

    private void notifyUser() {

        Snackbar snackbar =
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.message),
                        "An update has just been downloaded.",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
        snackbar.setAction("RESTART", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                appUpdateManager.completeUpdate();
            }
        });
        snackbar.setActionTextColor(
                getResources().getColor(R.color.snackbar_action_text_color));
        snackbar.show();
    }

    private void resume(){
            appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AppUpdateInfo>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(AppUpdateInfo appUpdateInfo) {
                    if (appUpdateInfo.installStatus() == InstallStatus.DOWNLOADED){
                        notifyUser();

                    }

                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: How to test this process?

Comment: 1. Uninstall original app from device.
2. Install the app from Google Play Store (I already had my app in Store, but if you don´t have it, you can create an alpha or beta version, without publish it in store).
3. Unistall the app again.
4. Generate signed apk with the new feature, with a lower versionCode than Google Play version
5. Install this apk.

Comment: Working... Thanks a lot

Comment: It's working fine with 9.0 but facing issue with 8.0 please tell whats the issue